# Golang convert list objects to string

Tags: go, go-reflect

I have two structs:

```
type A struct {
    BankCode           string `json:"bankCode"`
    BankName           string `json:"bankName"`
}
```

And:

```
type B struct {
    A 
    extra           string `json:" extra"`
}
```

And two slices:
`listsA []A` and `listsB []B`
I want to get `bankCodes` from `listA` and `listB`. `bankcodes` only contains `bankcodes`. It is a `[]string`

It will be so easy as using two function.

```
func getBankCodes(data []A) []string {
    res := make([]string, len(data))
    for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
        res[i] = data[i].BankCode
    }
    return res
}

func getBankCodes(data []B) []string {
    res := make([]string, len(data))
    for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
        res[i] = data[i].BankCode
    }
    return res
}
```

How to use one common function ?

Answer (score 1):

Well the clean solution would be to use an interface, since go doesn't support classic inheritance, so something like `[]parentclass` can't work. Interfaces however can only describe functions not a common field, so you have to implement a Getter (essentially).

```
// GetBankCoder provides a function that gives the BankCode
type GetBankCoder interface {
    getBankCode() string
}

// implement GetBankCoder for A (and indirectly for B)
func (a A) getBankCode() string {
    return a.BankCode
}
```

and make your `getBankCodes` work on that interface type, notice the parameter of the function as well as the statement inside the loop:

```
func getBankCodes(data []GetBankCoder) []string {  // <-- changed
    res := make([]string, len(data))
    for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
        res[i] = data[i].getBankCode()             // <-- changed
    }
    return res        
}
```

There are other solutions where the function parameter is of `interface{}` type and then reflection is used to assure you can actually do `.BankCode`, but I don't like those, as they are not adding more clarity either.

... However, I couldn't get the golang playground to make this work correctly without putting it into a `[]GetBankCoder` var first, before giving it to the function.

```
banks := make([]GetBankCoder, 0)
banks = append(banks, A{ BankCode: "ABC", BankName: "ABC Bank"})
getBankCodes(banks)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use one common function like so:

```
func BankCodes(data interface{}) []string {
    if reflect.TypeOf(data).Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("err: data is not slice")
    }
    slice := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(data))
    res := make([]string, slice.Len())
    for i := 0; i < slice.Len(); i++ {
        a := slice.Index(i).Interface().(BankCoder)
        res[i] = a.Bankcode()
    }
    return res
}
```

---

Code (try on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_KTq5Jyn6D)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    bs := []B{B{A{"BC1", "BN"}, "e"}, B{A{"BC2", "BN"}, "e"}}
    strs := BankCodes(bs)
    fmt.Println(strs)

    as := []A{A{"AC1", "BN"}, A{"AC2", "BN"}}
    strs2 := BankCodes(as)
    fmt.Println(strs2)

}

func BankCodes(data interface{}) []string {
    if reflect.TypeOf(data).Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("err: data is not slice")
    }
    slice := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(data))
    res := make([]string, slice.Len())
    for i := 0; i < slice.Len(); i++ {
        a := slice.Index(i).Interface().(BankCoder)
        res[i] = a.Bankcode()
    }
    return res
}

type A struct {
    BankCode string `json:"bankCode"`
    BankName string `json:"bankName"`
}

type B struct {
    A
    extra string `json:" extra"`
}
type BankCoder interface {
    Bankcode() string
}

func (a A) Bankcode() string {
    return a.BankCode
}
```